# Side Navigation styling issues

Tags: html, css

Would like to center the paragraph content with respect to the `.main-content`div that is to the right of the side navigation, but when I use `margin: 0 auto`nothing happens. I know I probably wrote the CSS wrong but I not sure of how to fix it.I would also like the white background of a link that's clicked to span the entire row of the div that holds the navigation. I doesn't reach the far left side.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var navElement = $('.nav-el');
 $('.content-area').hide();
  navElement.find('a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  navElement.find('.current').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
  $(this.hash).show().siblings().hide();
 }).first().click();
});
```

```css
.hide {
display: none;
}
body {

}
.container {
position: relative;
}

#contentBox {
border: 1px solid grey;
width: 960px;
height: 1000px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin: 0 auto;

}
.side-nav {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 250px;
background-color: green;
height: 100%;
}
.nav-el {
margin: 0;
}
.nav-el a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}
.nav-el a.current {
  background: white;
  color: orange;
}
.nav-el li {
list-style-type: none;
}
.main-content {

}
.content-area {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/samplestyle.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="contentBox">
      <nav class="side-nav">
        <ul class="nav-el">
          <li><a href="#nav1">nav element 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nav2">nav element 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nav3">nav element 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nav4">nav element 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nav5">nav element 5</a></li>
        </ul>
        
      </nav>
      <div class="main-content">
        <div id="nav1" class="content-area active">
          <h2>SECTION 1</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id quam eget risus vulputate 
            posuere. Duis rhoncus nunc nec quam consequat cursus. Quisque aliquam arcu sed nibh suscipit 
            hendrerit. Integer nisi massa, venenatis id bibendum gravida, consequat sit amet elit. Nulla 
            rutrum, lectus ut fermentum vehicula, leo sem cursus libero, ut euismod velit turpis at sapien. 
            Donec dui tellus, convallis non egestas lobortis, sodales nec massa. Vivamus sit amet viverra 
            odio. Sed eget egestas libero, nec condimentum orci.
          </p>        
        </div>
        <div id="nav2" class="content-area">
          <h2>SECTION 2</h2>
          <p>
            Vestibulum gravida quam id sem sagittis, vel ornare sapien ultrices. Morbi iaculis placerat metus, 
            in placerat neque ultrices eu. Duis laoreet, quam ac commodo hendrerit, nisi dolor bibendum urna, 
            eu facilisis orci eros ac odio. Fusce porta eros tristique, pellentesque mauris in, ullamcorper nisl.
            Morbi sollicitudin in magna vel tempor. Nullam placerat lorem quis orci dapibus efficitur. Mauris 
            tincidunt nisl ac sem dictum tempor. Etiam a molestie lorem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis 
            dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In fringilla ipsum id nisi ultricies, ac ornare urna pharetra.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="nav3" class="content-area">
          <h2>SECTION 3</h2>
          <p>
            Vestibulum gravida quam id sem sagittis, vel ornare sapien ultrices. Morbi iaculis placerat metus, in placerat 
            neque ultrices eu. Duis laoreet, quam ac commodo hendrerit, nisi dolor bibendum urna, eu facilisis orci eros ac 
            odio. Fusce porta eros tristique, pellentesque mauris in, ullamcorper nisl. Morbi sollicitudin in magna vel tempor. 
            Nullam placerat lorem quis orci dapibus efficitur. Mauris tincidunt nisl ac sem dictum tempor. Etiam a molestie lorem. 
            Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, 
            nascetur ridiculus mus. In fringilla ipsum id nisi ultricies, ac ornare urna pharetra.
          </p>    
        </div>
        <div id="nav4" class="content-area">
          <h2>SECTION 4</h2>
          <p>
            Sed tempor sodales molestie. Integer nec mauris varius, scelerisque turpis sagittis, tincidunt tellus. Ut vehicula 
            nec urna eu malesuada. Donec nec lacinia mauris. Sed elit mauris, vulputate nec tortor ut, ornare auctor nisl. Cras 
            a lorem nunc. Praesent vitae lorem velit. Proin tempus felis sed tortor luctus feugiat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur feugiat interdum orci et varius.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="nav5" class="content-area">
          <h2>SECTION 5</h2>
          <p></p> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The paragraph is centered if you look in the console. It's just that you menu hides it so you can't actually see it.

To center the text which is what I assume you want to do you can use `text-align: center;` on your `.main-content`:

```
.main-content {
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I'd also suggest you throw in some padding here to make it more readable and less ugly.

To allow the link to stretch full width you need to remove the padding of the `ul`:

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I would like to center the div's instead of the text inside the div

Comment: @web-dev text-align centers images as well. Check the console to see how the padding is affecting it, but most likely you will have to yes.